# Show only previous Business Day on a report

Tags: reporting, filters

I am attempting to show the previous Business Day's new Accounts in a report. I am unable to simply use Yesterday as the filter because Monday will then show Sunday results, not Friday.

The only potential solution I have been able to find involve creating a second report which only runs on Monday and shows the results of the previous three days - and then running the other report which shows Yesterday from Tues-Friday. That solution seems over complicated. Does anybody know of a more direct solution to this ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately filtering by weekdays is not supported in salesforce reporting currently.

You'd need to solve this by using a formula field on the Account object. In that formula field you can calculate the date on which the Account needs to appear in the report.

E.g. date formula field named 'Report date' with the following formula:

```
CreatedDate + (1*
CASE (MOD( DateValue(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1,7),7),
0,1,
1,1,
2,1,
3,1,
4,1,
5,3,
6,2,
1
))
```

This adds 1 day to the createdDate, except on Friday (day 5) and Saturday (day 6) it adds resp. 3 and 2 days. So accounts created in the weekend will also be grouped to be reported on Monday.

Then in your report, filter on 'Report date' equals TODAY.

Comment: Guy - thank you very much for your input. I've put the new field into the object but am unsure what exactly it's doing and how it would work for this. Could you please just give me a rundown of what it's doing ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Salesforce provides a nice explanation in their help files: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004512&language=en_US